# Nginx Maintenance Mode configuration

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

How can i turn on maintenance mode on nginx, I am hosting multiple Angular apps with Nginx. All of them run in their own containers. Maintenance page is located at /var/www/maintenance/. My current config is bellow

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name         example.eu;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.eu-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.eu-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    

# user ssl certificate check
ssl_client_certificate /home/user/CA/certs/users/klient.crt;
#ssl_crl /home/user/CA/crl/ca.crl;
ssl_verify_client on;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/graylog_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/graylog_error.log;



location /abc/ {
root /var/webapps/;
 }


location = / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/abcd;
 }

location /abcd {
rewrite ^/abcd(/css/|/js/|/img/)(.*)$ $1$2 break;
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_send_timeout 3600;
proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
 }


location /efgh/ {
rewrite ^/efgh(/css/|/js/|/img/)(.*)$ $1$2 break;
proxy_pass http://localhost:5005;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_send_timeout 3600;
proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
 }






server {
    if ($host = example.eu) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen   80;
    server_name         example.eu;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
server {
    ...
    set $maintenance '';
    if ($maintenance) {
        rewrite ^ /maintenance/ last;
    }
    ...
    location /maintenance {
        internal;
        root /var/www;
    }
}
```

To enable maintenance mode set `$maintenance` variable to any non-empty string, for example

```
set $maintenance 1;
```

and reload (it is [zero-downtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088363/how-nginx-reload-work-why-it-is-zero-downtime) operation) nginx.

Comment: thank you, it works ! :)

Answer (score 0):

### If the maintenance page only has HTML

No asset file (CSS, JS, ...)

```bash
location = @maintenance {
    root html/;
    # `break`: use this `location` block
    rewrite ^ "/maintenance.html" break;
}

location / {
    error_page 503 @maintenance;
    return 503;

    # ...
}
```

### For maintenance page that has asset file (CSS / JS / ...)

The flow of this is:

- If URI is `/`, `return 503`

  - Internal redirect to `/maintenance.html`
- If URI found in `maintenance` directory (for asset), return file with status 200
- All other request, redirect to `/`

```bash
# for handle maintenance web page
server {
    listen unix:/var/run/maintenance.nginx.sock;

    # for Windows
    # listen 8000;
    
    location @index {
        # use redirect because if URI has sub-folder ($uri == /path/path/),
        # the relative path for asset file (CSS, JS, ...) will be incorrect
        rewrite ^ / redirect;
    }

    location = / {
        # maintenance page URI
        error_page 503 /maintenance.html;

        return 503;
    }

    # use RegExp because it has higher priority
    location / {
        root html/maintenance/;

        # redirect all URI to index (503) page (except asset URI),
        # asset URI still return status 200
        try_files $uri @index;
    }
}

# original server block
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/maintenance.nginx.sock:;

        # for Windows
        # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    # ...
}
```

- You can put the config in a `maintenance.conf`, `include maintenance.conf` when in maintenance.

### If you need bypass some IP address

More detail [here](https://steelywing.github.io/note/Note/Nginx/Maintenance/)

> Ref: [Nginx Maintenance](https://steelywing.github.io/note/Note/Nginx/Maintenance/)